# rails4-autocomplete with belongs to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, autocomplete

I want to implement autocomplete via rails4-autocomplete

```
Rails 4.2.4
```

Here is the controller

```
app/controllers/samples_controller.rb

class SamplesController < ApplicationController
autocomplete :patient, :code
```

Here is the route file,

```
config/routes.rb 
resources :samples do
  get :autocomplete_patient_code, on: :collection
end
```

And that's the view 
    app/views/samples/_form.html.erb

```
<div class="field">

<%= f.label :patient_code %><br>
<%= f.autocomplete_field :patient_id, autocomplete_patient_code_samples_path %>

</div>
```

With this code I mange to get the autocomplete 
[image: autocomplete feature for sample form]

However I get invalid  foregin key error when try to save the sample that's because the patient's code is passed to the foregin key instead of ID. How do I fix this?

Here is the request Parameters:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"blabla",
 "sample"=>{"patient_id"=>"A123",
 "commit"=>"Create Sample"} 


Get "/samples/autocomplete_patient_code?term=A12" returns 
{"id":"15","label":"A123","value":"A123"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading the GitHub documentation of `rails4-autocomplete`, I devised the following solution:

Add `attr_accessor :patient_name` to your `Sample` model and modify the form as follows:

```
...
<%= f.autocomplete_field :patient_name, autocomplete_patient_code_samples_path, id_element: '#patient_id' %>
<%= f.hidden_field :patient_id, id: 'patient_id' %>
...
```

With this change whenever you select any patient name, that patient's ID will be updated on the hidden field and it will be submitted as patient_id.

Hope this solves your problem.

Source: [Github](https://github.com/peterwillcn/rails4-autocomplete#getting-the-object-id)

Comment: Unfortunatelly this did not solve the problem, ` "sample"=>{"patient_code"=>"CODEA", "patient_id"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Sample"} `

Comment: Can you post your '_form.html.erb'?

Comment: Thank you for forcing me take a look at my _form. Had some typo.

Comment: No problem. I figured something would be amiss in the form itself, otherwise it should work as stated on GitHub. I am happy it is working now! Cheers!

Comment: I have a problem when editing form the autocomplete field is empty,  that I could not fix, was wondering if you can help me, have posted the question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35793814/autocomplete-field-is-empty-when-editing-form)