# autocomplete field is empty when editing form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-autocomplete

I have a sample model in which belongs_to a patient model.Using [rails-jquery-autocomplete](https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete) I have managed to implement an autocomplete field where one can search patient's code and it works well. However when editing the form, the patient code is empty on the form. 
How should I fix it?

App/views/sample/_form.html.erb

```
    <div class="field">
       <%= f.label :patient_code %><br>
       <%= f.hidden_field :patient_id, id: 'patient_id' %>
       <%= f.autocomplete_field :patient_code, autocomplete_patient_code_samples_path, id_element: '#patient_id' %>
    </div>
```

Comment: Nothing in your example looks wrong and you haven't posted enough I think for us to see what's wrong.  I recommend checking the documentation as the problem may be in other parts of your code: https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete  My initial suspicion is you have something wrong with the `id_element`.  When you open up your browser inspector console do you have a JS error?

Comment: No, I don't get any error. [here is the link to more details of my implementation ] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35573168/rails4-autocomplete-with-belongs-to-association)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue while editing the saved model, a quick workaround would be as follows:

```
...
<%= f.autocomplete_field :patient_code, autocomplete_patient_code_samples_path, id_element: '#patient_id', value: (!@sample.new_record?)? @sample.patient.code : '' %>
...
```

Assuming that the instance variable is `@sample`. Modify it according to your scenario. Cheers!

Comment: @user1876128 I'm sorry my ternary operator syntax was wrong. Kindly check my updated answer.

Comment: This works with a little change can you update your answer so that I approve ,`<%= f.autocomplete_field :patient_code, autocomplete_patient_code_samples_path, id_element: '#patient_id', value: (!@sample.new_record?)? @sample.patient.code : '' %>
`